# Excel Chart to show events over time (network up/down) but I only have half the data (downtime)

Tags: excel, time, charts

I'd like to visualise the following data in a meaningful way:

```
Failure Start         Length
22/06/2021 08:46:54   00:00:30
22/06/2021 09:06:06   00:00:05
22/06/2021 09:24:51   00:00:07
22/06/2021 09:27:30   00:00:06
22/06/2021 09:28:12   00:00:09
22/06/2021 09:37:32   00:00:05
22/06/2021 09:41:39   00:00:05
22/06/2021 09:42:58   00:00:05
```

I am using a small utility called Net Uptime Monitor to monitor when my laptop network connection drops at home. I want to be able to compare this to other devices in my home using the same application.

Ideally I'd like to pull the data together from multiple devices and compare them easily (visually) - to see if there are specific times the network drops all all devices or if it is just one specific device.

I am not sure on how to best visualise the data. I imagine a stacked bar chart with uptime in green and downtime in red - so the chart would be alternating red/green/red/green with the length of the sections representing the length of the up/down time. Different bars would represent different devices.

However I only have the downtime data. I know I can calculate the uptime:

```
failure time start (n) - [ failure time start (n-1) + failure length (n-1) ]
```

but this calculation would end up being a new column on the same row, not its own row/entry. I don't want to manually add a row after each entry and make this calculation.

The length of time I'll look at might get quite long - a whole day or even a few days - so the solution ought to be able to scale well.

I imagine there are other applications that would solve this specific challenge for me (network monitoring tools) - but I want to solve this using what I have. I'm just a guy working from home wondering if he can learn to use Excel with time based data on something that is of mild annoyance and therefore likely to maintain my interest long enough to complete the learning opportunity.

Thanks in advance.
Tim